# How hashmap store objects internaly

Tags: java, data-structures

Yesterday in my class my professor teach hash, and i want to know one thing, how hashmap store objects?

I know about entry class.

But i know arraylist can start by default by 10 elements or you can set this in constructor, and if need more elements that is set, will create another array copying the values...

So, how hashmap grow?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> An instance of HashMap has two parameters that affect its performance: initial capacity and load factor. The capacity is the number of buckets in the hash table, and the initial capacity is simply the capacity at the time the hash table is created. The load factor is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its capacity is automatically increased. **When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current capacity, the hash table is rehashed (that is, internal data structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has approximately twice the number of buckets.**

(emphasis mine)

The source code is also distributed with the JDK if you want more implementation details.

Comment: Yes, i understood what you told me, but there is something...

The load factor i can determine?

And what happens with the hashcode of each key when a rehash happens?

Comment: The load factor is passed as argument to the constructor. It's 0.75 by default. This is documented in the javadoc. Why don't you read it? A rehash, by definition, recomputes the hashes and reassigns each key to a new bucket.

Answer (score 1):

The `HashMap` has an internal array of [Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) that when no other size is specified, defaults to 16.

I have made a small piece of code, where you can see the actual map size, and it's internal array size, so you can compare. Just change the for loop so it can grow as far as you want.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++){
        m.put(i, i);
        Field table = m.getClass().getDeclaredField("table");
        table.setAccessible(true);
        int tableLength = ((Entry[])table.get(m)).length;

        System.out.println("Map size: " + m.size());
        System.out.println("Internal table size: " + tableLength);
    }

}
```